# Obtain log of when audio starts and stops

Tags: audio, logging

In Android 11, at least in the version Google uses for their phones, all audio apps can be controlled with media buttons you see if you pull down the notifications/top/task/whatever bar.

My question is: **How can I get a log of when I stop and start audio from the top bar media buttons?**

The log needs to include *timestamps*, so I can see how long something has played for. It would preferably also include some *information about what was being played*, such as the title of the track or podcast. It also need to always go at least one week back in time, which seemingly rules out using `logcat` the standard way.

Any way of doing it would be okay. For example:

- An app that can monitor audio plackback on the phone.
- Getting system logs through ADB.
- "System traces"?

As far as I can tell, Android destroys logs from before that last reboot, but I might be wrong about this. The log I get by running `adb logcat` gives me the information I need. It seems I am only able to get logs since the last reboot though. If I can access old logs, that would be a solution to the problem and you would get the bounty for helping me achieve this.

If there is a way to know when I start and stop playing audio from *within an app*, I would also accept an answer that lets me get this information. I don't mind if the information comes from the media buttons or not, I just want to know when audio starts and stops playing on the device.

Comment: Try this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232252/131553

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this app does something different from what I want though. It looks like it just records screen time. I usually don't start the app but control the playback through the media controls in the notification bar. And of course I don't have my screen on while listening to a podcast.

Comment: If "audio player" is an app, I think AppOps can be used to achieve what you want. But it requires elevated privileges, root or at least ADB.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I meant by AudioPlayer. I checked out AppOps but it seems to only have to do with permissions.

Comment: Based on [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls), the media controls on Android 11's notification is using `MediaSession` and `MediaRouter2` APIs, though I haven't tested if using such API will create a log in the logcat or not.

Comment: Those "media control notification" that include the buttons belong to the app that plays the music. Therefore on an unrooted device other apps don't have options to access or monitor the buttons and the music state. Therefore you have to use an player app that internally writes the log you want or you have to modify your favorite music player in a way that it creates the desired log. For unrooted devices I don't see other options.

Comment: @user.S the first line [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager): *"App-ops are used for two purposes: Access control **and tracking**"*. [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager#startWatchingActive(java.lang.String[],%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.app.AppOpsManager.OnOpActiveChangedListener)) does exactly what you are looking for. I don't know of an app but it's not impossible to make one. But again, it requires elevated privileges.

Comment: @ AndrewT., @Robert, thanks, it annoyed me that I wasn't sure what the thing I'm talking about is. I know that I can get a lot of information from logcat so if I can keep the log from getting destroyed, that's enough. The log exists, my only problem is that it is cut off at the last reboot.

This is for personal use so the method doesn't have to be perfect and **requiring root is okay** even if not my preferred solution. I can find what log messages are associated with pressing play and pause by myself. It is okay even if it comes from the apps themselves.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, okay, well that sounds more useful. I found a couple of apps that deal with AppOps but one is unavailable for my device and the other's tracking functionality wasn't working.

Comment: @user.S Unfortunately logcat is totally out of scope for your use case. See [this question on details how logcat works](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103746/2241). Depending on the device, the logcat buffer size and the logcat traffic frequency it can happen that logcat overwrites events just a few seconds old.

Comment: @IrfanLatif App-ops looks interesting but by the description it seems to track only permission relevant actions such as RECORD_AUDIO. Other audio related events are not mentioned. Do you have practical experience with that part of Android? From my perspective this seems to be the predecessor of the current "dynamic permission request" system of Android.

Comment: @Robert there are also PLAY_AUDIO and TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS ops: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java#887. Might be one of them or some other op is necessarily invoked when an app plays media. But I'm not sure about it. I do have experience with Access Control part ([PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) is based on it) but not much with the Tracking part.

Comment: @Robert, Ah okay, a few seconds won't be enough. I've tried a few apps that claim to capture system logs and save them to a file but none of them seem to work. The optimal thing might be an app that monitors the logs and saves lines that match a pattern.

Comment: @user.S Logcat access from within an app was removed in Android 4.4 (or 4.2 - not 100% sure about the version). Since that time you need root permissions to access logcat.

Comment: I know it's restricted but the apps claim that I can work around that with adb. This one for example: https://f-droid.org/packages/com.tortel.syslog/